# Multi-font @fontface

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a fontface with several fonts in it, in such a way that:

`font-weight: normal` resolves to `Roboto-Regular.ttf`

`font-weight: lighter` -> `Roboto-Thin.ttf`

`font-weight: bold` -> `Roboto-Black.ttf`

`font-weight: bolder` -> `Roboto-Bold.ttf`

At the moment I'm defining a @fontface for each.

Comment: Yes. [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) also accepts `font-weight` as one of its controls.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with one font-face rule. You should be able do it with a font-face rule for every font that you want to use.

Comment: @Ouroborus Ah yes, that works!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in one statement just be aware the more font variations you add it will add size to the font library so be selective :)

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

or as an import in css you can do...

`@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap");`

and per your comment for sourcing fonts locally I don't know a way to do it in a concise manner...but the following might work

`@font-face { font-family: "Roboto"; src: url("/fonts/Roboto-Regular.eot"); src: url("/fonts/Roboto-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("/fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff") format("woff"), url("/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"); font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; }`

`@font-face { font-family: "Roboto"; src: url("/fonts/Roboto-Bold.eot"); src: url("/fonts/Roboto-Bold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/fonts/Roboto-Bold.woff2") format("woff2"), url("/fonts/Roboto-Bold.woff") format("woff"), url("/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf") format("truetype"); font-weight: 500; font-style: bold; }`

Comment: Can you rewrite the answer to do it for local files instead of querying google fonts? :)

Comment: ok updated my answer.  Might need a bit of tweaking.

Comment: Using that method the last @fontface defined seems to be the one everything resolves to

Comment: hmmm...I was sort of winging it.....try changing `font-weight: 500; font-style: bold; }` to `font-weight: 700; font-style: bold; }` I think i put the wrong weight in my example for bold